# как заполнить массив пропустив некоторые элементы?

Tags: c#

Как заполнить массив - пропустив например одну ячейку в середине - т.е что то типа:

```
for (i = 0; i < len ; i++)
                {
                    SliderArray[i< L2 <i] = s1;
```

-как срезы в python, или что то подобное?

Может дела не в синтаксисе, а в алгоритмах - пишите- буду рад почитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали решение:

```
  if(i == len/2)
        array[i] = null
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот код пропустит элемент в середине. Пропускаемый элемент зависит от выражения в if. Если вам необходимо исключить диапазон, используйте условие типа
if(!(i > 1 && i < 3))

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if(i != len/2)
        SliderArray[i] = i;
```

Comment: "пропустив например одну ячейку в середине"